# require.js:1895 GET magento2/pub/static/version1572681098/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/iost.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: magento2

I have developed a payment gateway module and has code  in `requirejs-config.js` like this.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento::iost/dist/iost.min'

    }
};
```

But i am getting the error in console. How can i resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call js file like below method in require-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/js/iost/dist/iost.min'
         }
    }
};
```

Your js file must be here

> app/code/Iostpay/Iostpaymagento/view/frontend/web/js/iost/dist/iost.min.js

Comment: Okay, I have changed the file to this location.

`app/code/Iostpay/Iostpaymagento/view/frontend/web/js/iost/dist/iost.min.js`

And in `checkout_index_index.xml`  i have included the head like this.

`<head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <script src="Iostpay_Iostpaymagento::iost/dist/iost.min.js"/>
 </head>`

the error I am facing

` (index):26 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento3/pub/static/version1572687569/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/iost/dist/iost.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: Is there is something I've mistaken? :|

Comment: You got this error in console?

Comment: yes i have got error in console

Comment: Did you removed require-config.js and run upgrade, content-deploy commands?

Comment: No, this is my 'requirejs-config.js' code
`var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/js/iost/dist/iost.min'
   
    }
};`

And a head in `checkout_index_index.xml`

`<head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <script src="Iostpay_Iostpaymagento::js/iost/dist/iost.min.js"/>
  </head>`

Comment: And yes i run ugrade and conten-deploy on every code update

Comment: You can have either any one of the file for enqueue...`require-config.js` or `checkout_index_index.xml`...Please remove require-config.js and run those commands.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100606/discussion-between-garry-and-ranganathan).

Comment: Thanks, I prefer doing this with require-config.js

Comment: removed the head from `checkout_index_index.xml` and adding the script to `requirejs-config.js`  is giving an error of `404 not found`
 
`require.js:1895 GET http://127.0.0.1/magento3/pub/static/version1572692851/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Iostpaymagento.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: And this is the code in `require-config.js `

`var config = {
   map: { 
    '*': {
      lazyloadScript:'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/js/iost/dist/iost.min'
     }
    }
   };
`

Comment: But in error it showing `Iostpaymagento.js`..Did you enqueued this js file?

Comment: No i have only mentioned it in require-config.js as given in my previous comment.

Comment: Then search Iostpaymagento.js in your env to find where you enqueued.

Comment: It is not there in env file.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat -https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100606/discussion-between-garry-and-ranganathan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100668/discussion-between-garry-and-ranganathan).